# Native Ad Unit id

Tags: android, admob

I have integrated [Native ads](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6239795) within my app using this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native#using_adlistener_with_an_adloader.)

Test ads are displaying well. From where should I get my AdMob Unit Id for these Native ads ? It says Native ads are in beta, so can I integrate it within my app. 
Also, should I use [DFP](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/native) for Native ads ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't integrate it in your app, as admob native ads are only available for selected publishers.
DFP is for ads management, it is not an ad provider.

**Update**

Admob has now native ads express that all developers can implement in their apps.

check the docs: [Admob native express ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express)